# awk: identify column by condition, change value, and finally print all columns

Tags: awk, toupper

I want to extract the value in each row of a file that comes after `AA`. I can do this like so:

```
awk -F'[;=|]' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i=="AA"){print toupper($(i+1));next}}'
```

This gives me the exact information I need and converts to uppercase, which is exactly what I want to do. How can I do this and then print the entire row with this altered value in its previous position? I am essentially trying to do a find and replace where the value is changed to uppercase.

EDIT:

Here is a sample input line:

```
11  128196  rs576393503 A   G   100 PASS    AC=453;AF=0.0904553;AN=5008;NS=2504;DP=5057;EAS_AF=0.0159;AMR_AF=0.0259;AFR_AF=0.3071;EUR_AF=0.006;SAS_AF=0.0072;AA=g|||;VT=SNP
```

and here is a how I would like the output to look:

```
11  128196  rs576393503 A   G   100 PASS    AC=453;AF=0.0904553;AN=5008;NS=2504;DP=5057;EAS_AF=0.0159;AMR_AF=0.0259;AFR_AF=0.3071;EUR_AF=0.006;SAS_AF=0.0072;AA=G|||;VT=SNP
```

All that has changed is the `g` after `AA=` is changed to uppercase.

Comment: please add sample input lines and expected output for those to help in testing possible solutions..

Comment: I have edited my question to include this information. Thanks.

Comment: if you have GNU sed, would this work for all your input cases? `sed 's/\bAA=[^;=|]*\b/\U&/'` .. if you don't have GNU sed, try `perl -pe 's/\bAA=[^;=|]*\b/\U$&/'`

Comment: Thanks! That works perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following `awk` may help you on same.

```
awk '
{
  match($0,/AA=[^|]*/);
  print substr($0,1,RSTART+2) toupper(substr($0,RSTART+3,RLENGTH-3)) substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
}
'   Input_file
```

Comment: Both answers work perfectly but I accepted this one as it uses awk as per the question.

Comment: @spiral01, glad that it helped you, cheers and happy learning :)

Answer (score 1):

With `GNU sed` and `perl`, using word boundaries

```
$ echo 'SAS_AF=0.0072;AA=g|||;VT=SNP' | sed 's/\bAA=[^;=|]*\b/\U&/'
SAS_AF=0.0072;AA=G|||;VT=SNP
$ echo 'SAS_AF=0.0072;AA=g|||;VT=SNP' | perl -pe 's/\bAA=[^;=|]*\b/\U$&/'
SAS_AF=0.0072;AA=G|||;VT=SNP
```

- `\U` will uppercase string following it until end or `\E` or another case-modifier
- use `g` modifier if there can be more than one match per line